# UITextfiels bounds, strange behavior

Tags: ios, uitextfield, bounds

I don't understand what happening with a simple code. I want to resize the width of an `UITextField` but when I do it, it also changes its `origin.x`. I tried many configurations but I can't find a solution.

The textfield is in an `UIView`:

```
containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,20,200,30)];
textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

And here is the code for changing its width:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

textfield.bounds = CGRectMake(textfield.bounds.origin.x,
                                  textfield.bounds.origin.y,
                                  textfield.bounds.size.width + 110, 
                                  textfield.bounds.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Each time, `origin.x` changes to something like -55 (but `NSLog` prints 0). Do you have any idea? I would like to maintain always the same `origin.x`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the bounds, try changing the frame:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

textfield.frame= CGRectMake(textfield.frame.origin.x,
                              textfield.frame.origin.y,
                              textfield.frame.size.width + 110, 
                              textfield.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

From the docs:

```
Changing the bounds size grows or shrinks the view relative to its center point
```

And this seems to be the problem in your case.